# How to assign items of an array to different variables in each cycle

Tags: java

I have an array of unknown length (created at runtime). It is displayed and processed using a for loop. I want to keep the processing unchanged but assign the first value to a variable in first loop cycle and second value to a different variable in second cycle. Should I use if statement or there is a more sophisticated way. E.g

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{

    if ( i == 0)
        firstVariable = array[i];
    if ( i == 1)
        secondVariable = array[i];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are certain that the first and second values exist, then simply use `array[0]` and `array[1]` without any loops.

Comment: But this way each time the loop executes the values will be updated and in my case the variables are static. Or I may assign them out of the for loop but this way it will not look very professional.

Comment: I meant: assign `fstVar = array[0]` and `sndVar = array[1]` outside the loop. You need to be wary of the cases where `array.length < 2`.

Comment: you question is a little bit unclear … do you need those different variables just inside the loop? then just write ´var = tmp;´ otherwise you should specify if you just gave 2 vars as example but will actual need 5 var for a lenght-5-array or if you always need just two vars from an array of unknown lenght

Comment: not always but let say inside the loop structure I want 5 variables to get 5 values from an array of 20 length. How we can do it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
if (array.length > 1) {
    firstVariable  = array[0];
    secondVariable = array[1];
}
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // The `for` loop, I assume exists anyway to do some other stuff.
}
```